# Python Error while trying to read form a csv file to a dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to read from a csv file to a dictionary. The problem is that I have 3 values per line (not just 2) and want to transform to a dict where the first value is the key and the last 2 values are combined to a single value (e.g. using a list or a tuple). As an example, I have the following inside csv:

```
Calcium Enriched 100% Lactose Free Fat Free Milk,2346,57876.0

Large Organic Omega3 Brown Eggs,2568,86280.0

Roasted & Salted Shelled Pistachios,919,29358.0

Chocolate Peanut Butter Protein Bar,801,21296.0
```

...

I want the output to be something like this:

```
{'Calcium Enriched 100% Lactose Free Fat Free Milk': [2346,57876.0]}

{'Large Organic Omega3 Brown Eggs': [2568,86280.0]}

{'Roasted & Salted Shelled Pistachios': [919,29358.0]}

{'Chocolate Peanut Butter Protein Bar': [801,21296.0]}
```

I tried to do it the normal way like this:

```
with open('avg_prod_reorder_time.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    avg_prod_reorder_time = dict(reader)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a dict as you wanted:

```
avg_prod_reorder_time = {r[0]: r[1:] for r in reader if r}
```

A dict consists of key/value pairs, but your data is not formatted in pairs. The code above takes the first element as a key and forms a list of all remaining elements. The condition `if r` skips empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't use csv. Just read files line by line and split it.

```
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, *value = line.rstrip("\n").split(',')
        result = {key: list(value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a csv file like this,

**some.csv**

```
Hello ,1,2
There ,2,3
Friend ,4,5
```

You can try this,

```
import csv
mydict = {}
with open("some.csv","r+") as c:
    r = csv.reader(c)
    for row in r:
        mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]
print(mydict)
```

output:

```
{'Friend ': ['4', '5'], 'Hello ': ['1', '2'], 'There ': ['2', '3']}
```

**Explanations:**

This is the part where you'll be interested in,

```
r = csv.reader(c)
for row in r:
    mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Here we are assigning

`mydict[row[0]]` with `row[1:]`

i.e for first one

`mydict['Hello']` with `row[1:]` i.e `[1,2]`  # List slicing

Similarly for the other lines.

**Note:**

List slicing means slicing a list based on indexes, 
try this if you didn't know about them. The general form is like this,

**your_list[start:stop]**

**Note** Start is inclusive stop is exclusive

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0]
1
>>> a[1:]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a[2:]
[3, 4]
>>> a[3:]
[4]
>>> a[:2]
[1, 2]
>>> a[:3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[:1]
[1]
```